# Making a plot with geom lines of my data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've started using R and I'm learning how to use it,

I have a data frame of a stock, I want to show with ggplot/plot how the lock and open gate changes by the date,
I would like to have x- as the date while y1-Open Gate,y2-Lock Gate,y3-the Change.

```
Date      Lock.Gate  Change Open.Gate
<fctr>    <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>
26/09/2019    237.4  1.15   234.7   
25/09/2019    234.7  0.73   233.0   
24/09/2019    233.0  0.13   232.7   
23/09/2019    232.7  0.00   232.7   
22/09/2019    232.7  1.26   229.8
```

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: also check this site out http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use `ggplot` contained in the tidyverse package. Unfortunately since the `Change` values are smaller than the other two, the plot lacks good readability.

```
# prepare the initial dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(
    cbind(

        c(237.4,234.7,233.0,232.7,232.7),
        c(1.15,0.73,0.13,0.00,1.26),
        c(234.7,233.0,232.7,232.7,229.8)
    )
)

df <- cbind(c('26/09/2019','25/09/2019','24/09/2019','23/09/2019','22/09/2019'), df)

colnames(df) <- c("Date","Lock.Gate","Change","Open.Gate")

df

        Date Lock.Gate Change Open.Gate
1 26/09/2019     237.4   1.15     234.7
2 25/09/2019     234.7   0.73     233.0
3 24/09/2019     233.0   0.13     232.7
4 23/09/2019     232.7   0.00     232.7
5 22/09/2019     232.7   1.26     229.8

#install & load the required package if not available
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

#plot
ggplot(data=df, mapping= aes(x=Date)) + 
    geom_point(mapping=aes(y=Open.Gate, color = "Open.Gate")) +
    geom_point(mapping=aes(y=Lock.Gate, color = "Lock.Gate")) +
    geom_point(mapping=aes(y=Change, color = "Change")) +
    ylab(" ") +
    scale_colour_manual("", 
                    breaks = c("Lock.Gate", "Open.Gate", "Change"),
                    values = c("green", "red", "black")
                    )
```

[image]

EDIT

To obtain the desired output you should run:

```
#change date format
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
#plot
ggplot(data=df, mapping= aes(x=Date)) + 
  geom_line(mapping=aes(y=Open.Gate, color = "Open.Gate")) +
  geom_line(mapping=aes(y=Lock.Gate, color = "Lock.Gate")) +
  ylab(" ")
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do that only with the lock and open gate but with geom lines ? Not points